# Can GeoServer WPS accept external WMS as input?

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, wps

I'm reading here:

http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/processing/processes/formats.html#raster-inputs

that GeoServer can accept HTTP Requests as Input when a Raster is required.
Documentation states this raster must be "a WCS GetCoverage request or equivalent". (I know is NOT the official documentation but Boundless Server's one, still I feel it applies also to the Open-Source GeoServer)

I need to know if specifying a **WMS** (as an http URL) can do the job.. ..and hopefully an example.

The test I did with the default GeoServer's "WPS request builder" all failed complaining a proper Input was not found in the provided HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. As mentioned in several other question here a WMS returns a **picture** of a map not a map. If you want the actual georeferenced scaled data for a raster layer use the WCS service.

Answer (score 1):

A WPS can issue requests to any remote service via POST or GET that you will embed, verbatim, in the Execute request.
Whether or not GeoServer is able to handle the output of that call is separate issue.
For example, the remote WMS server might be able to return geo-referenced imagery too, GeoServer does for example, this request returns a GeoTIFF:

http://cloudsdi.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/eumetsat/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eumetsat%3Asea_surface_temperature&bbox=-68.0%2C19.5%2C-50.0%2C33.5&width=768&height=597&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers

This request will return something suitable for any process taking in input a "coverage", that is, a georefenced raster (e.g., gs:CropCoverage).

A WMS will normally return a non georeferenced image. That per se does not preclude the usage of WPS thought, you just need to find (or write) a process that takes as input a plain image (e.g., one that adjust its contrast for example).